# How do I connect these two models in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-1.6

I've got two models that look kind of like this:

```
class People(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

class Income(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    person_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    income = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to be able to fetch any number of people and their related income in one query. But since there is no foreign key here, I can't do `People.objects.filter(age=40).select_related('income')`. How do I make such a query without making a raw query? If it's not possible, what is the best way to alter the tables in order to make such a query?

Comment: Why aren't you using a foreign key here? The `person_id` should be a foreign key to `People`, right?

Comment: It should be noted, having a `ForeignKey` object in Django does not require a database level foreign key to work. So even if your database doesn't allow changes, you can make this work easily by adding `person = models.ForeignKey(People, blank=True, null=True)`

Comment: Say what? I had no idea. That changes the situation radically.

Comment: @Wolph: If you provide your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @trevorDashDash Adding to Wolph answer, you can safely omit the `id` field definition, as Django will add it automatically (and it's a reserved python word) and, if you need it, you can specify a db column name for your fields using the `db_column` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django expects `ForeignKey` objects to simply have the name `yourname_id` (although even that is overridable). Since Django also has support for databases without real foreign key support every bit for foreign key support is handled by Django itself instead of the database so there is no real need for database foreign keys. Except requiring database consistency that is (there are certain race conditions where it can be convenient to have this).

In most cases however, this will work without any foreign keys in your database (note that the `id` column is added implicitly by Django):

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

class Income(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(People, blank=True, null=True)
    income = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class People(models.Model):
    #add your field here.

class Income(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(People, blank=True, null=True)
    #add your income field here (Integer field)....
```

This will create a table (in your database) in which income will be related to people. By default this foreign key is the auto-generated id field of User table (by default id fields, which are also primary keys in this example, are auto-generated for each table, unless specified otherwise)